# Run Anaconda script in Windows from C++/Qt program

Tags: python, windows, qt, anaconda

Okay, weird thing. This works perfectly fine in Linux, but I cannot get it to work in Windows. Problem might be that I'm not working in Windows a lot these days...

I've got a Python script that I want to run from a C++/Qt program. So I installed Anaconda and within the "Anaconda Prompt" I installed the package containing the script via pip. I've got the full path to the Python script (defined as an entry_point in the packages's setup.py, so it's actually an exe file) and try to start it like this:

```
proc = new QProcess(this);
connect(proc, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, &MainWindow::receivedText);
connect(proc, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &MainWindow::receivedText);
proc->start(python_script, arguments);
```

Where python_script and arguments are the full path to the python script and its arguments. When I run this from the "Anaconda Prompt", it works fine, but from my Qt program I get a "NumPy not installed" error, although it's definitely installed. Could it be that I have to run "conda activate" somehow first? Sorry, I'm not really familiar with Anaconda, only using it in Windows... How would I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use conda activate?

Comment: In Linux I'd say that I need a shell in which I can first call "conda activate" and then the script. I assume that I could write both into a batch/powershell script, but that would include writing another file to disk. 
Or do you mean use it in a normal shell? I didn't let Anaconda set the PATH on install, so that doesn't work. Or would that be necessary? I'd expect the installed script would set the path as it would in Linux...

Comment: Okay, played around with it a little more. The main question is now: how to I activate anaconda without a shell?

Answer (score 1):

can you open a dos prompt shell from your code? If so, you can get anaconda to start within that shell and then run your conda activate commands, etc.

Try this command to see if this is an option, you may need to change the paths from miniconda3 depending on what anaconda app you are using:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\user\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\user\miniconda3
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually wanted to avoid that, and instead read stdout/stderr directly...

Answer (score 0):

Found a method that works: instead of calling the script directly as "script.exe arguments", I can run it through the Python interpreter as "python.exe script.exe arguments", which seems to work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I keep having the same issue when I switch servers, so posting a solution which always works for me:

> conda install -c conda-forge implicit